# Can anyone help me to code Reverse algo function for CRC64 in C#?

Tags: .net, c#, hash, checksum

I am working on CRC64 Reversing algorithm on C# but unable to code it. If anyone can help me out, it will be nice of him. I am desperate to complete the coding.

Comment: You probably want [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). However don't re-post this over there, the question will be migrated for you.

Comment: Why specifically do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. CRC is a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). Hash functions **cannot** be reversed. The best you can do is try and find collisions for a given hash, but they are *designed* to be hard to find such collisions..

Answer (score 0):

You definitely won't be able to reverse it, since you lose critical data doing the "forward" computation that would be necessary to the "backward" computation.  You can try to brute-force it if you have some idea of what the input might have been, but because a CRC is weak there might be a lot of collisions (meaning you might find lots of possible inputs that could have generated your result) in which case you have no way of knowing which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure he's asking for a 'reflected' algorithm.
The 'standard' and 'reflected' algorithms are an exact mirror
image of each other, including the polynomial used in each.
A message created/checked on one-endian system should not be
reversed on other-endian system as this can harm the checks
ability to identify burst errors. An 'mirror' algorithm on
the other-endian system will produce a check that exactly
matches the transmitted check value. Not sure if this code
is still needed? I could probably do it for you with the
original code to be reflected.